# How to increment ID before any insert with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, auto-increment

It looks like NH gets MAX(ID) only once, at first insert and then stores this value internally, this causes me some problems when other processes inserts data. Then I have not actual ID and duplicate key exception is thrown.

Lets imagine we have table `Cats`

```
CREATE TABLE Cats(ID int, Name varchar(25))
```

Then we have corresponding mapping done with FluentNhibernate

```
public class CatMap : ClassMap<Cat>
{
    public CatMap()
    {
      Id(m=>m.ID).GeneratedBy.Increment();
      Map(m=>.Name);
    }
}
```

All I want to achieve is to insert my `Cat` records with ID's generated by NHibernate using `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Cats` **before any** insert. Executing Session.Flush after any commit dosnt work. I'v done some investigation using SQL Server profiler, and this sql stetement is executed only once (at first insert) - other inserts doesnt force to retreive actual MAX(ID). I know that other algorithms like HiLo are better, but I cant replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found out, the NHibernate Increment id generator was not intended for use in a multi-user environment. You state that using a HiLo generator is not an option so you're left with these options:

- use the Native generator and change the id column to use the database supported identity mechanism
- use the Assigned generator and write code to determine the next valid id
- create a Custom generator where you implement the [IIdentifierGenerator](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2358742&sid=7d3c8c59f46e887dda86520b9a398396) interface to do what you need

Below is sample code for a custom generator that uses a generalized proc to get an ID for a given table. The main issue with this approach is that you must wrap the code in something like a [Unit of Work](http://nhibernate.info/doc/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.html) pattern to ensure the 'select max(id) ..." and the insert are covered by the same database transaction. The [IIdentifierGenerator](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2358742&sid=7d3c8c59f46e887dda86520b9a398396) link has the XML mapping you need to wire up this custom generator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Engine;
using NHibernate.Id;
using NHibernate.Persister.Entity;
using NHibernate.Type;

namespace YourCompany.Stuff
{
    public class IdGenerator : IIdentifierGenerator, IConfigurable
    {
        private string _tableName;
        // The "select max(id) ..." query will go into this proc:
        private const string DefaultProcedureName = "dbo.getId";

        public string ProcedureName { get; protected set; }
        public string TableNameParameter { get; protected set; }
        public string OutputParameter { get; protected set; }

        public IdGenerator()
        {
            ProcedureName = DefaultProcedureName;
            TableNameParameter = "@tableName";
            OutputParameter = "@newID";
        }

        public object Generate(ISessionImplementor session, object obj)
        {
            int newId;
            using (var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                var tableName = GetTableName(session, obj.GetType());

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = ProcedureName;

                // Set input parameters
                var parm = command.CreateParameter();
                parm.Value = tableName;
                parm.ParameterName = TableNameParameter;
                parm.DbType = DbType.String;

                command.Parameters.Add(parm);

                // Set output parameter
                var outputParameter = command.CreateParameter();
                outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                outputParameter.ParameterName = OutputParameter;
                outputParameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;

                command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

                // Execute the stored procedure
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var id = (IDbDataParameter)command.Parameters[OutputParameter];

                newId = int.Parse(id.Value.ToString());

                if (newId < 1)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        string.Format("Could not retrieve a new ID with proc {0} for table {1}",
                                      ProcedureName,
                                      tableName));
            }

            return newId;
        }

        public void Configure(IType type, IDictionary<string, string> parms, Dialect dialect)
        {
            _tableName = parms["TableName"];
        }

        private string GetTableName(ISessionImplementor session, Type objectType)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_tableName))
            {
                //Not set by configuration, default to the mapped table of the actual type from runtime object:
                var persister = (IJoinable)session.Factory.GetClassMetadata(objectType);

                var qualifiedTableName = persister.TableName.Split('.');
                _tableName = qualifiedTableName[qualifiedTableName.GetUpperBound(0)]; //Get last string
            }

            return _tableName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Done by implementing Custom ID Generator.

Comment: @Dariusz I'm stuck with a similar Problem, could you please provide some additional info on how you implemented this?

Comment: As I've said, I have implemented my custom IdGenerator @nozzleman