# NHibernate: Increment function not getting next sequence value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, nhibernate, increment

I get the following error when I try to save an Entity with NHibernate:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-00001: unique constraint (FEMADEV.TRN_INFLOW_DETAILS_HIS_PK) violated
```

My Controller Code:

```
TrnInflowDetailsHis trnInflowDetailsHis = Mapper.Map<TrnInflowDetailsHis>(trnInflowDetailsAud);
trnInflowDetailsHis.InflowSeq = trnInflowDetailsAud.Id;
trnInflowDetailsHisService.Add(trnInflowDetailsHis);
```

Mapping Code:

```
 public class TrnInflowDetailsHisMap : ClassMap<TrnInflowDetailsHis>
 {
    public TrnInflowDetailsHisMap()
    {
        Table("TRN_INFLOW_DETAILS_HIS");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("INFLOW_ID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.InflowSeq).Column("INFLOW_SEQ");
        Map(x => x.TranRef).Column("TRAN_REF");
        Map(x => x.Currency).Column("CURRENCY");
     }
  }
```

The problem here is, `GeneratedBy.Increment()` is working fine, but sometimes it is not incrementing next sequence value. I do not know what is the problem. So please any one help me to find the solution.

Comment: When and where it happens? development or production?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7889535/43846

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that issue is more about **multi concurrent instances**, rather than a bug in the `increment` generator

The exception [ORA-00001](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00001_unique_constraint_violated.htm) means:

> An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key. For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.

Other words, someone already INSERTed ID value, which current thread tries to use. And that could easily happen in **multi app instance** accessing the same DB with an ID generator `Increment`.

The doc [5.1.5.1. generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) :

> increment
>
> - generates identifiers of any integral type that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. **Do not
>     use in a cluster.**

So, just change this generator to anything else. The `increment` is maybe for development, or for almost immutable types. Or if you can be sure, that there is only one instance (one application) running at time.